# How do I write this so that the Error: relation "photos" does not exist and same error for "users" does not occur

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, syntax-error

Im trying to make these two tables however the users and photo table both have a foreign key that refers to the other table and they come up with errors. How would I change this code so that there's no error.

```
create table people (
    id              serial,
    family_names    text,
    given_names     text,
    displayed_names text,
    email_address   text,
    primary key (id)
);

create table users (
    userid              integer,
    website             text,
    date_registered     date,
    gender              GenderValue,
    birthday            date,
    password            text,
    portrait            integer,
    
    primary key (userid),
    foreign key (userid) references people(id),
    foreign key (portrait) references photos(photoid)
);

create table photos (
    photoid             serial,
    title               TitleValue,
    date_uploaded       date,
    date_taken          date,
    description         text,
    technical_details   text,
    safety_level        safetyLevel,
    visibility          visibilityLevel,
    owns                integer,

    primary key (photoid),
    foreign key (owns) references users(userid)
);
```

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CjKS.png)

Comment: A properly normalised databse should have foreign key relations in one direction only. You have them in both. If you have correctly normalised your schema this will no longer be an issue

Comment: @FredStark: Hmm, what normal form would that violate and why?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "forward" reference from the table definition and add it as an `alter table` statement after all tables have been created:

```
alter table users add constraint fk_users_photos
    foreign key (portrait) references photos(photoid);
```

In fact, one style of table creation is simply to create all tables with no foreign key references, and then to use `alter table` for all of them after the table definitions.  This prevents any errors and allows circular references.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9c9c7003726d927006d1fdcc7f73a4bb) is a db<>fiddle.  Note that your code has custom types which I changed to base types in the fiddle.